# Mysql function CONTAINS and GEOMFROMTEXT does not working

Tags: mysql

So i have this method that contains a geometry function from mysql :

```
select *, (SELECT SUM(t_o.value) FROM tree_operations t_o WHERE t_o.operation_id = operations.id) operationTreeValue, (SELECT COUNT(t_o.id)  FROM `tree_operations` t_o WHERE t_o.operation_id = operations.id) operationTreeNumber, (CASE\r                          WHEN operations.type = 'pieces' THEN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) FROM `pieces` p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT piece_id FROM `piece_row_operations` WHERE operation_id = operations.id))\r                          WHEN operations.type = 'rows' THEN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(r.number) FROM `rows` r WHERE r.id IN (SELECT row_id FROM `piece_row_operations` WHERE operation_id = operations.id))\r                          END) AS typeName from `operations` where operations.id IN (SELECT t_o.operation_id FROM `tree_operations` t_o WHERE t_o.tree_id IN (SELECT t.id FROM `trees` t WHERE t.coordinates IN (Contains(GeomFromText('POLYGON(49.816472 35.971209,49.7868 35.970981,49.788668 35.947219,49.15201 35.947905,49.816472 35.971209)'))))) order by `operations`.`id` desc
```

But surprisingly it doesn't work on server (while it's perfectly fine in local)
After spending chunk load of time (running query on different environments and so on ) i couldn't get any solid answer .
is there anything wrong with my query or is it the functions that are not working anymore??
p.s : my mysql version in the local is 5.7 and server is mariadb 10.2

Comment: Mysql Versions please.

Comment: @P.Salmon question has been edited.

Comment: GeomFromText() and GeometryFromText() are deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Use ST_GeomFromText() and ST_GeometryFromText() instead. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html

Comment: It's dangerous having differing local and server versions but throwing in a completely independently maintained server into the mix is adventurous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of mysql functions as GeomFromText() are deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6;

Use MariaDB@latest && ST_GeomFromText() and ST_ (other functions) instead